# How to create complex arguments with Zeep (SOAP client for Python) and nest data?

Tags: python, soap, soap-client, python-3.5

I need to pass some nested data to my SOAP client, I think I know how to create the complex arguments...

```
id = ucmdb.get_type('ns17:ID')
```

Now I want to give some "arguments" to this 'ci', how can I do this?
I'll show what I mean with an example using the old Suds which I know how to use:

```
id = ucmdb.factory.create('ns17:ID') #complex
id._temp = "true" #first "argument"
id.value = dict['logical_name'] #second "argument"
```

How can I do that with Zeep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the section "Using SOAP headers" in http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/in-depth.html.

I was able to use that info to write a script that integrates with Zuora, and needs complex types in the Soap Header. See http://community.zuora.com/t5/API/Python-quickstart/m-p/10779/highlight/true#M403

Comment: It says "SOAP headers are generally used for things like authentication", soooo is it used for this, I don´t know a lot about web services, so a little help or explanation about this could be needed please. Thanks!

Comment: Tried what you did: `intProp_type = client.get_type('ns17:IntProp')        intProp = intProp_type(name = "slots", value = 56)` but it didn´t work, an error appears: KeyError: "No type 'IntProp' in namespace http://schemas.hp.com/ucmdb/ui/1/types. Available types are: {http://schemas.hp.com/ucmdb/ui/1/types}ClassNameAndIcons, {http://schemas.hp.com/ucmdb/ui/1/types}ClassNameAndIcon"

Comment: Can you explain me what is the method "client.service.create" for?

Comment: "client.service.create" invokes the create method (as defined by the wsdl). There may or may not be such a method in your wsdl. It looks as if your wsdl does *not* contain a type 'ns17:IntProp'.

You can examine what is in your wsdl as follows:

python -mzeep <wsdl>